# Tips to reduce opengl 3 & 4 frame-rate stuttering under Linux

Tags: linux, opengl

In recent years I've developed several small games and applications for OpenLG 2 and ES.
I'm now trying to build a scene-graph based on opengl 3+ for casual “3D” graphics on desktop systems. (Nothing complex like the unreal- or crytec-engine in mind.)

I started my development with OsX 10.7 and was impressed by Apples recent ogl 3.2 release which achieves equivalent results compared to windows systems.

Otherwise the results for Linux are a disappointment. Even the most basic animation is stuttering and destroys the impression of reality. The results did not differ between the windows toolkits  freeglut and glfw. (The Extensions are loaded  with glew 1.7)

I would like to mention that I'm talking about the new opengl core, not the old opengl 2 render-path, which works fine under Linux but uses the cpu instead of the gpu for complex operations.

After watching professional demos like the “Unigine heaven demo” I think there is a general problem to use modern real-time 3D graphics with Linux.

Any suggestions to overcome this problem are very welcome.

**UPDATE**:

I'm using: 
AMD Phenom II X6, Radeon HD57XX with latest  proprietary drivers (11.8) and Unity(64Bit).

You could take my renderloop from the toolkit documentation:

```
do {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    ...
} while (!glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) && glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED));
```

I'm using **VBOs** and all transformation stages are done with shaders. Animation timing is done with **glfwGetTime()**. This problem occurs in window and full-screen mode. I don't know if a composition manager interferes with full-screen applications. But it is also impossible to demand from the user to disable it.

**Update 2**:

**Typo**: I'm using a HD57XX card.

GLX_Extension: http://snipt.org/xnKg

PCI Dump: `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Juniper [Radeon HD 5700 Series]`

X Info: http://pastie.org/2507935

**Update 3:**

Disabling the composition manager reduces, but did not completely remove the stuttering.
(I replaced the standard window manager with "ubuntu classic without extensions")
Once a second the animation freezes and ugly distortions appear:

(Image removed - Not allowed to post Images.)

Although Vertical synchronisation is enabled in the driver and checked in the application.

Comment: You haven't really told us anything about what you're doing or the problem in general. You say that your GL 2 path uses the CPU for "complex operations", and you intimate that your GL 3 path uses the GPU. OK, but what are these "complex operations"? What are you rendering? What is your GL 2 rendering path like, and how is it different from your GL 3 rendering path?

Comment: There is a great difference between GL2 and GL3 core. GL3 moves many operations for transformations, mappings and animations to shaders (vertex, geometry and fragmet shader). Shaders written in GLSL are executed on the GPU.

Comment: I am well aware of the differences between GL 2 and GL 3. But that doesn't answer my questions. It tells us nothing of what the two rendering paths look like. It could be anything, from the way you transfer your vertex data to your shader logic to how you set your uniforms to anything else. Without knowledge of what you're actually doing, your problem simply cannot be diagnosed. Also, you seem to be under the mistaken belief that GL 2 means "can't use shaders." You can use shaders just fine in GL 2; GL 3 core just makes it _mandatory_.

Comment: What Nicol Bolas said. It would be a great help if you could post the output of 'glxinfo', 'xdpyinfo', '/usr/sbin/lspci' and 'ps awx' so that we see what's running on your box.

Comment: Sorry, the system isn't accessible at the moment. My Linux development machine is AMD Phenom II X6, Radeon HD54XX, Ubuntu 11.4 (Natty) with latest proprietary drivers (11.8) and Unity as Desktop.

Comment: "Once a second the animation freezes and ugly distortions appear:" wow, that a new one. May I suggest you start a vanilla X server without a fancy desktop environment. Ubuntu requires you to do this as root *sic*, or with sudo. First get a leightweight WM, like openbox (apt-get install openbox), then 'xinit /usr/bin/openbox -- :20' - right mouse click gives you a menu. I suspect some program taking screenshots of each window every second for thumbnails or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running Linux we require a bit of detailed information:

- Which hardware do you use?

  Only NVidia, AMD/ATI and Intel offer 3D acceleration so far.
- Which drivers?

  For NVidia and AMD/ATI there are propritary (nvidia-glx, fglrx) and open source drivers (nouveau, radeon). For Intel there are only the open source drivers.

  - Of all open source 3D drivers, the Intel drivers offer the best quality.
  - The open source AMD/ATI drivers, "radeon" have reached an acceptable state, but still are not on par, performance wise.
  - For NVidia GPUs, the only drivers that makes sense to use productively are the propritary ones. The open source "nouveau" drivers simply don't cut it, yet.
- Do you run a compositing window manager?

  Compositing creates a whole bunch of synchronization and timing issues. Also (some of) the OpenGL code you can find in the compositing WMs at some places drives tears into the eyes of a seasoned OpenGL coder, especially if one has experience writing realtime 3D (game) engines.

  KDE4 and GNOME3 by default use compositing, if available. The same holds for the Ubuntu Unity desktop shell. Also for some non-compositing WMs the default skripts start *xcompmgr*  for transparency and shadow effects.
- And last but not least: How did you implement your rendering loop?

  A mistake oftenly found is, that a timer is used to issue redisplay events at "regular" intervals. This is not how it's done properly. Timer events can be delayed arbitrarily, and the standard timers are not very accurate by themself, too.

  The proper way is to call the display function in a tight loop and measure the time it takes between rendering iterations, then use this timing to advance the animation accordingly. A truly elegant method is using one of the VSync extensions that delivers one the display refresh frequency and the refresh counter. That way instead of using a timer you are told exactly the time advanced between frames in display refresh cycle periods.

Comment: I updated my question. I also tried to use the VSync (I know this trick from the good old C64 times.). This works perfectly with OsX and Windows (at least with the latest drivers) but fails on Linux.

Comment: Unfortnately the whole Compositing thing completely messes up VSync. Technically it was rather simple to fix, but whenever I tried to explain the X.org developers I got back blank stares (in email form); and I can't fix it myself, because it requires patching the drivers. There are 2 things to do: If a window is redirected (into an off-screen buffer) doublebuffering is switched off (compositing is doublebuffering), directed Windows (v)sync against a deadline, set by the compositor, depending on the estimated time for drawing the composition.

Comment: For tests I emulated this using XDamage extension and XSync on single buffered applications. Works quite nicely. Also window managers/compositors could to such simple things like putting the topmost window out of composition if it doesn't have an alpha channel.

Comment: Thank you. You just answered another question.  Could I help to convince the X.org developers to fix this bug? Is Wayland an alternative? I thought the first release is scheduled for next year?

Comment: Wayland is even worse. It got one thing right: Compositing. But several things totally wrong (IMHO). Wayland places the burden of rendering on the clients. This streches so far, that the clients are even responsible for rendering their window decorations and getting their Z-stacking done - let a client crash and have a hard time getting it moved away. However nothing will be messed up more than fonts. Also performance will suffer, since most toolkits will use software rendering and only push their rendered windows to Wayland for compositing. I spend hours on IRC discussing with the developers.

Comment: X.org having bad VSync is not so much a bug, but some features missing. The biggest problem I see there is, that some (not all) of the high profile X.org developers lack basic understanding of sampling theory, most notably the Nyquist theorem and many of their (fruitless) attempts on fixing the issues result from this. They know how to shuffle around data efficiently, but as soon as signal processing theory is concerned things get awful. Unfortunately signal synchronisation IS signal processing.

Comment: Similar holds for PulseAudio where the principal author "invented" zero latency, but actually implemented a rather poor PLL (with rather large oscillations) between system time and sample clock. I considered sending him a few IEEE reports from the 1960ies, explaining how to do it better, but then I remember how well he copes with criticism (not good). The whole Linux media stack is in a poor state right now, sadly enough. Any the people in charge tend to piss off those who point out the problems in their design, due to inability to cope with critic.